# What is the probability of someone guessing a specific number?

Tags: probability

I think of a number between 1-600, and ask people to guess the number that I'm thinking of.  So long as they know that it is something between 1-600, I understand that each individual's probability of guessing the correctly is 1/600.  But how do I calculate the probability that anyone will guess correctly at all?

It would seem to me, that if I only ask 10 people, the probability of any one of them guessing correctly is quite low, whereas if I asked say 10,000 people, the probability that one or more of them would guess correctly is quite high, but I don't know how to calculate that probability.

Am I right in assuming that it is a formula based on the range (e.g. 1-600) and the number of guesses (e.g. 10 or 10,000 etc)? and if so, what is that formula?

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to calculate this is by figuring out the probability that no one guesses correctly.

For each individual person, the probability that they don't guess correctly is $\frac{599}{600}$. So, if you have $10$ people, the probability that they all fail to guess correctly is
$$\left(\frac{599}{600}\right)^{10}.$$
This means the probability that at least one gets it right is
$$1-\left(\frac{599}{600}\right)^{10}.$$
Can you generalize this?

Answer (score 1):

I will assume that the guesses are completely random (i.e., the probability that a person guesses a fixed number $1\leq k \leq n$ is $\frac{1}{n}$ for any $k$), and that the guesses are all independent of each other. Say that the number you thought of is $k_0$ and that you ask to $m$ different people. Then, the probability that *at least* one of them is right is one minus the probability that all of them are wrong. That is to say:
$$P(\text{at least one is right}) = 1 - P(\text{all of them are wrong}) = 1 - (P(\text{wrong}))^m = 1 - \frac{(n-1)^m}{n^m},$$
the last two equalities being a consequence that the trials are independent (that is why we multiply $m$ times the probability of being wrong) and they all have the same probability of being wrong, $\frac{n-1}{n}$.

Edit: just to clarify, in your case, $n=600$